# how to write and define properties of consumer using spring cloud stream

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have one producer and one consumer both of them are producing and consuming data from a topic named  ***cloud-stream*** , the producer is successfully able to produce a message to topic ***cloud-stream***
but when I am trying to print consume the data more specifically just to log it on the console, I am not seeing any logs on the console.
I am using Stream-bridge to send message as following:

**producer: application.properties**

```
#SPRING-CLOUD_STREAM
spring.cloud.stream.source = order-out-0
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.order-out-0.destination = cloud-stream
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.order-out-0.producer.partitionCount =3
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers = localhost:9092
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.replicationFactor = 1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.content-type: application/json
```

**Producer Code :**

```
    @Component
    @Slf4j
    public class EventHelper {
    
        @Autowired
        private StreamBridge streamBridge;
        public void generateEvent(OrderDto orderEvent) {
            streamBridge.send("order-out-0", orderEvent);
            log.info("event send create order, event: {}",orderEvent);
        }
}
```

similarly, I have a consumer (payment-service), both producer and consumer are spring boot application as following:

***consumer: application.properties***

```
spring.application.name=payment-service
server.port = 9091
#SPRING-CLOUD_STREAM
spring.cloud.function.definition = consume
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers = localhost:9092
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.replicationFactor = 1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.order-in-0.destination = cloud-stream
```

the code in consumer where I am trying to log the message (a message that I need to consume):

```
@Configuration
public class EventConsumer {

    @Bean
    Consumer<OrderDto> consume() {
        return event -> {
            System.out.println("Consumed message ==========>" + event);
        };
    }
}
```

the above configuration class is in subpackage on class marked as @SpringBootApplication
i.e class marked as @SpringBootApplication is in package `com.payment.service` and EventConsumer  is in package `com.payment.service.consumer` what i can think of is, I messed up some configuration in ***consumer: application.properties***

I tried looking at various articles, was not able to understand how to solve this.

Comment: 1) Properties files shouldn't have spaces around the `=`. 2) How exactly are you checking the producer is actually writing to Kafka rather than only logging in your service for the consumer to do anything?

Comment: @OneCricketeer i created one another consumer with plain java code, able to consumer the message

Comment: removed spaces around = , did not work @OneCricketeer

Comment: In the logs, do you see the Kafka `ConsumerConfig` output?

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes

Comment: Can you [edit] the post to include them please? For example, if you have  `auto.offset.reset=latest`, then you would need to start the consumer before running the producer

Comment: @OneCricketeer can you have a look at my code on GitHub, it is just a small code, both payment and order service are present on GitHub on the master branch, adding a link to GitHub if you like you can have a look https://github.com/ashish27upadhyay94/order-service https://github.com/ashish27upadhyay94/payment-service

Comment: i am also getting this error in Kafka logs => members, 0 of which are static. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2022-01-28 01:03:01,588] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Member consumer-anonymous.ff734396-22d7-4b1a-92b4-8b4ee9dd1721-2-d0f3709d-0d61-4adf-aff2-2428f6241a7d in group anonymous.ff734396-22d7-4b1a-92b4-8b4ee9dd1721 has failed, removing it from the group (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2022-01-28 01:03:01,591] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0

Comment: I see `INFO` there. Not `ERROR`. The group coordinator can move around between instances.